# Access content of first "post" of a taxonomy

Tags: hugo

I try to access the content of the first entry of a Taxonomy. I can get the basic fields like `{{.Name}}` with the following code:

```
<ul>
{{ range $key := .Site.Taxonomies.tags.ByCount }}    
    <li>
    {{ with index .Pages 0 }}
       {{ .Name }} <-- Name of the first post
    {{end}}

    <a href="/tags/{{ .Name | urlize }}">{{ .Name }}</a> ({{ .Count }})</li>
{{ end }}
</ul>
```

But how do I access a custom field of the first content item within the taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

The fields can be accessed by using `{{ .Params }}`.